# Determine whether a given linear map is injective/surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example, let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^3_3\to\mathbb{Z}^2_3$ be a linear map with
$$\phi\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+x_3\\x_2-x_1+x_3\end{pmatrix}$$

How do I determine, if $\phi$ is injective/surjective? Can we use the fact that if (edited) $\dim(\operatorname{ker}\phi)=0$, then the linear map is injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear map is injective if and only if $\dim\ker\phi=0$ (not when $\le1$).

---

The matrix of the linear map with respect to the canonical bases is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A standard Gaussian elimination yields the reduced row echelon form (RREF)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the matrix has rank $2$. Therefore the map $\phi$ is surjective. It cannot be injective, because the nullity is $3-2=1$. Indeed a basis of the kernel of $\phi$ is given by the single vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
obtained as a nonzero solution of the linear system $\phi(x)=0$, by looking at the RREF.

Comment: If $\dim (im \phi)=\dim \mathbb{Z}^2_3\implies $surjective?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Certainly so. And the dimension of the image is the same as the rank of any associated matrix.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The map is injective if and only if $\ker\phi=\{0\}$. But it follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\ker\phi\geqslant1$ and therefore $\phi$ is *not* injective.

But it is surjective; this follows from the fact the both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ belong to the image of $\phi$: $\phi(1,1,0)=(1,0)$ and $\phi(0,1,0)=(0,1)$.